# SQL - Accessing data in 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (table A and table B) that have a 1 to many mapping. For every record in table A, I want to check if any of its events in table B occur after 2010. For example:

```
      Table A                          Table B
      ID     REGISTER                  ID     DATE
      A       qwer                     A      1995-01-01
      B       ghlk                     A      1997-01-31
      C       thasdj                   A      2006-03-15
                                       B      2001-03-15
                                       B      2003-04-03
                                       B      2021-08-01
                                       B      1995-01-01
                                       C      2001-01-01
                                       C      2010-01-01
```

Therefore, the resulting Table would be

```
          Table C
        ID    Register
        A       qwer
        C       thasdj
```

Because for ID A and C, none of their events happens after 2010.

THis is the script I tried using but I'm not sure why it's not working. Any help

```
        SELECT *
        INTO Table C
        FROM Table A
        where ID not in( 
        
        SELECT distinct ID from Table B
        where [DATE] >= 2011-01-01
```

Comment: I would write the select using inner join.. but you already got an answer..
SELECT A.ID, A.REGISTER
FROM
A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
WHERE B.DATA >= TO_DATE('2010', 'YYYY')

Comment: Syntax and the ssms tag indicates that you are using ms sql server, not mysql. Please, pay attention to tagging, you may get misleading or incorrect answers if the answerers believe that you use a different product!

Comment: `2011-01-01` works out at `2009`, presumably you meant a date value `'2011-01-01'`. Also `distinct` makes no sense in a semi-join subquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with `insert into {tablename} (list column) select` syntax

```
INSERT INTO C ( ID, Register )
SELECT  A.ID, A.Register
FROM    A  
WHERE A.ID not in ( 
        SELECT distinct ID from Table B
        where [DATE] >= 2011-01-01
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *not exists* for this task. Presumably your example query is contrived however note you must properly delimit object names that contain spaces, are reserved words etc and a date value must be quoted.

```
select *
into TableC
from TableA a
where not exists (
  select * from TableB b 
  where b.Id = a.Id and b.[Date] >='20110101'
);
```